# 'iostream' file not found when compiling on WSL

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use window's subsystem for linux on my local machine to compile a c++ program that works on my school's linux computers, but I get the following error when I try to compile:

```
$ make

In file included from cs221util/HSLAPixel.cpp:9:
cs221util/HSLAPixel.h:11:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
Makefile:23: recipe for target 'HSLAPixel.o' failed
make: *** [HSLAPixel.o] Error 1
```

I have installed the following items so far. What should I do from here?

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
```

MakeFile:

```
EXE = pa3
EXETest = pa3test

OBJS_EXE = HSLAPixel.o lodepng.o PNG.o main.o toqutree.o stats.o
OBJS_EXET = HSLAPixel.o lodepng.o PNG.o testComp.o toqutree.o stats.o

CXX = clang++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++1y -stdlib=libc++ -c -g -O0 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic 
LD = clang++
#LDFLAGS = -std=c++1y -stdlib=libc++ -lc++abi -lpthread -lm
LDFLAGS = -std=c++1y -stdlib=libc++ -lpthread -lm 

all : pa3 pa3test

$(EXE) : $(OBJS_EXE)
    $(LD) $(OBJS_EXE) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(EXE)

$(EXETest) : $(OBJS_EXET)
    $(LD) $(OBJS_EXET) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(EXETest)

#object files
HSLAPixel.o : cs221util/HSLAPixel.cpp cs221util/HSLAPixel.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) cs221util/HSLAPixel.cpp -o $@

PNG.o : cs221util/PNG.cpp cs221util/PNG.h cs221util/HSLAPixel.h cs221util/lodepng/lodepng.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) cs221util/PNG.cpp -o $@

lodepng.o : cs221util/lodepng/lodepng.cpp cs221util/lodepng/lodepng.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) cs221util/lodepng/lodepng.cpp -o $@

stats.o : stats.h stats.cpp cs221util/HSLAPixel.h cs221util/PNG.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) stats.cpp -o $@

toqutree.o : toqutree.h toqutree.cpp stats.h cs221util/PNG.h cs221util/HSLAPixel.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) toqutree.cpp -o $@

testComp.o : testComp.cpp cs221util/PNG.h cs221util/HSLAPixel.h toqutree.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) testComp.cpp -o testComp.o

main.o : main.cpp cs221util/PNG.h cs221util/HSLAPixel.h toqutree.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) main.cpp -o main.o

clean :
    -rm -f *.o $(EXE) $(EXETest)
```

Comment: Shot in the dark here. I see gcc referenced, not g++. gcc is the C compiler. Make sure your makefile is using g++ to compile C++ code.

Comment: Which WSL distribution are you using? I am unable to reproduce this with a simple code with Ubuntu 16, also what @user4581301 said

Comment: Please also include the compilation command that your makefile produces.

Comment: I'm new to this so I'm not sure if I'm looking at the right thing, but I got the same directories when I replaced gcc with g++. @anand_v.singh I'm using ubuntu 18.04, it worked when I ran C code but not C++.

Comment: @molbdnilo I updated my question to include the makefile, I'm not sure what compilation command means.

Comment: Your makefile says that you're using clang++, not g++, and libc++ rather than libstdc++. Is suspect that you haven't installed libc++.

Answer (score 1):

It worked after I installed libc++. Thank you!

```
sudo apt-get install libc++abi-dev
```